# Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError on visit('http://google.com')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

My goal is to use cucumber + capybara that run in a displayed browser with selenium (chromedriver).

**Gemfile**

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rspec-rails'#, '~> 3.3.2'
end
```

**features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'selenium-webdriver'    # Setup selenium-drivers for capybara

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

**test.feature**

```
Feature: Google
  Scenario: When I go to google, I am supposed to be on google
  Given I am on google
```

**test_steps.rb**

```
Given(/^I am on google$/) do
  visit('http://google.com')
end
```

When I run **cucumber**, it ends up in error

> redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects.
>   (Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError)

It doesn't even open the browser...What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In test_steps you are saying when you are on Google to go to google?  That would redirect all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to this post: https://gist.github.com/pranav7/0f377b91a8b2cafe71bd

I needed to put this in **features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 120
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :http_client => client)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
```

Comment: The only part of this "fix" that made a difference is setting of default_driver.  In your initial try you could have just set `Capybara.default_driver  = :selenium_chrome` and it would have done the same thing.  The reason for this is that the normal default driver (rack_test) doesn't support external urls, and the default setup requires to tag scenarios with @javascript if you want them to use the javascript_driver.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the difference between `Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome` and `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome` is a bit blury to me but it works now.